# is $1/x^2$ a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am not sure if $1/x^2$ is a Convex function. When I differentiate it twice I get $6/x^4$ which is $\geqslant 0$ for $x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$. This shows it is a convex function over the entire $x$ in $(-\infty, +\infty)$. But when I see the [graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%2Fx%5E2%20graph&rlz=1C1SQJL_enIN801IN801&oq=1%2Fx%5E2%20graph&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3684j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I am confused. If I draw a chord from $x = -1$  to $x = 1$ the function doesn't seem convex.

Comment: You have to be careful about points where the derivative is not defined.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @EuxhenH

Comment: Your function has a point of discontinuity which is at $0$ and the derivative is not defined there. You have to consider the two intervals separately, i.e., $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. You will discover that your function is convex in each interval separately, but not on the entire real line.

Comment: $0$ is not in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the domain when you describe a function and in this particular note that in the definition of the convex function, they require the domain to be convex.

$\frac1{x^2}$ is not defined at $0$ and the test that you used requires the function to be twice differentiable.

$\frac1{x^2}$ is convex is convex if the domain is the set of positive numbers or the set of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ is undefined when $x=0$. But,
$\frac{1}{x^2}$ is convex if $D=\{x:x>0, x<0, x\subset R \}$

Answer (score 0):

A [function is convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) in $[u,v]$ if for all $t\in[0,1]$ we have:
$$f(tu+(1-t)v)\leqslant tf(u) + (1-t)f(v)\qquad(1)$$
The left side is the function's value in $[u,v]$ whereas the right represents a line from point $(u,f(u))$ to $(v,f(v))$. If that line runs above (not below) the function for all values in the interval, then we say *the function is convex* in that interval.

This definition (1) is much more elementary than using second derivative, in particular (1) does not require any kind of smoothness like existence of derivatives of $f$, it doesn't even require $f$ to be continuous.  The criterion using 2nd derivative follows from (1) provided 2nd derivative exists, of course.

We can extend (1) to cases where $f$ is not defined everywhere in an obvious way so that it still makes sense: Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$ then we can say $f$ is convex in $D$ if (1) holds for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $u, v\in D$ for which also $tu+(1-v)t \in D$.

For example if we apply it to
$$\begin{align}
f:\mathbb R^{\neq0}&\;\to\;\mathbb R\\
x&\;\mapsto\; 1/x^2
\end{align}$$
with $v = 1 = -u$ the condition turns into:
$$\frac{1}{\big((t\cdot(-1)+(1-t)\cdot1\big)^2}
= \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}
\leqslant t\cdot1 + (1-t)\cdot1=1$$
i.e. $(1-2t)^2\stackrel!\geqslant1$ for $t\in[0,1], t\neq1/2$.  However, that inequality is only satisfied for $t=0$ and $t=1$.  For any $t\in(0,1)$ that inequality does *not* hold.

In many cases, the condition using 2nd derivative is much more convenient, it can however only be used to conclude convexity over intervals.  But we have to keep in mind that
$$
f\text{ is convex in } U\cup V \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad (f\text{ is convex in } U \text{ and } f\text{ is convex in } V )
$$
but the converse it not true in general.